# angularjs $routeParams.x giving me a value of undefined

Tags: angularjs, routes

I set up my routing as follows:

```
.when('/:countryName/:categoryName', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
  })
```

Problem is I am having trouble pulling the values from my $routeParams object

For example when I do this:

```
$scope.parameters = $routeParams;
```

$scope.parameters equals the following object 
{"countryName":"Japan","categoryName":"Football"}

However if I try assign the following:

```
$scope.parameters = $routeParams.countryName;
```

$scope.parameters is undefined

[PLUNKER of issue I am having](http://embed.plnkr.co/TAHOBq5XGUUQQFY8KI5p/preview)

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to unserialize $routeParams with angular.toJson($routeParams);

Comment: This doesn't work. As far as I can see the $routeParams is already an object

Comment: From documentation: The service guarantees that the identity of the $routeParams object will remain unchanged (but its properties will likely change) even when a route change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a very short $timeout before you try to access $routeParams.

```
$timeout(function () {

    console.log("$routeParams.x: ", $routeParams.x);

    continueAppLoad();

}, 100);
```